OpenLayers snap feature on mobile to move (translate) to new position
I'm rewriting an app that we formerly used with GoogleMaps Api v3 to Openlayers (v4.6).
We use a longclick (from the famous library ol-ext from http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/) to add new features (trees in this case) on the map.
To give the user the possibility to add new features in the field on mobile devices, we use a transparent circle with a cross in the center. This circle is big enough,so that the user can move it with his finger, without hiding the cross in the middle, that corresponds to the precise position.
On desktop or laptop this works fine and the feature can easily be moved since the mouse pointer transforms to a hand.
On mobile (Safari) it is hard to 'catch' the feature and most of the time the map is moved and not the feature. How can I improve this on mobile, so that the user can move the feature without moving the map. I don't want to disable dragPan temporarily.
 
Here the relevant code I use so far:
 // transparent circle with cross inside
 var tCross = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
    anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
    anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
    anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
    src: './images/mapmarker.png',
    scale: 0.7
    }),
 });

// Longtouch interaction using ol-ext from http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/
var longtouch = new ol.interaction.LongTouch({
  pixelTolerance: 5,
  
  // Handle longtouch > create a new feature
  handleLongTouchEvent: function(e) {
    var f = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(e.coordinate));
    f.setStyle(tCross);
    temp.getSource().addFeature(f);
    
  // deactivate longtouch to prevent to add a second feature 
  map.getInteractions().forEach(function(interaction) {
     if (interaction instanceof ol.interaction.LongTouch) {
     interaction.setActive(false);
     }
  }, this); 
  
  // allow feature to be moved on map   
    var dragInteraction = new ol.interaction.Translate({
          features: new ol.Collection([f]),
    });
    
  // on translateend open myModal-window with form to add attributes to feature and save to database. 
    dragInteraction.on('translateend',function(){
    var latlng = ol.proj.transform(this.getGeometry().getCoordinates(), 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
        document.getElementById("lat").value = latlng[1];
        document.getElementById("lng").value = latlng[0];
        $('#myModal').modal('show'); //=> saveData() :1732
    },f);

    map.addInteraction(dragInteraction);
  }
});  // End longtouch 

// add longtouch to map
map.addInteraction(longtouch);


Your biggest problem is probably having to touch the visible areas of the icon as there is no hit detection on transparent regions.
However Fill in a Circle style is always detected, so you could style using a Circle and RegularShape (adjusting the radius of each to suit your requirements):
var tCross = [
  new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'transparent',
      }),
      radius: 50,
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'white',
        width: 2,
      }),
    }),
  }),
  new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.RegularShape({
      radius: 10,
      radius2: 0,
      points: 4,
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'white',
        width: 2,
      }),
    }),
  }),
];


Thanks Mike, this works now great. I already remarked, that hit detection does not work on transparent regions. I now changed the color of the circle from transparent to 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)' which now works fine and the whole circle is detected, so that the user can move it.

If you are using v4.6 transparent fill might not be detected.  From v6.0 any fill is detected.
